# Change Label of UISwitch

Tags: ios

I have to change the label of a `UISwitch` from ON-OFF to YES-NO.

I want this method to be implemented in separate class and then accessed by other classes.

I have tried to implement the snippets provided in the cook book, but without success

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711180/changing-the-text-on-a-uiswitch

Hope to help you, Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can use images for `on` and `off`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *offImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *onImage;
```

**image size is of 77*27**

Answer (score 1):

`UISwitch` uses images for drawing. To change the text of a `UISwitch`, you would have to set the `onImage` and `offImage` properties of the `UISwitch` to use images with your custom text. This could be done directly on a `UISwitch` instance, or using `UIAppearance` to set your custom image across all `UISwitch` instances in your app:

```
[[UISwitch appearance] setOnImage:onImage];
[[UISwitch appearance] setOffImage:offImage];
```

Unfortunately, setting custom on and off images for UISwitch is not functional in iOS 7 or later. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiswitch_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/onImage):

> In iOS 7, this property has no effect.
>   In iOS 6, this image represents the interior contents of the switch. The image you specify is composited with the switch’s rounded bezel and thumb to create the final appearance.

And it has not been marked as deprecated. In iOS 8 this still seems to be the case, unfortunately. Customizing the colors of a `UISwitch` still works, but using custom images does not. To customize the images (and thus text) of a switch you will have to use a custom control class.