# Changing the text on a UISwitch

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

The UISwitch currently says ON and OFF. Can I change the text to YES and NO?

Would it be hard? Or do I just rephrase the question I ask the user?

Comment: The UISwitch doesn't need to say ON/OFF. It can be オン/オフ or even two graphics depending on the locale.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Heh - that's how I got here. :-)

Comment: [Domestic Cat](http://domesticcat.com.au/) has published a custom controller that allows for custom labels and frame sizing. It is released under the MIT license and simply requires inclusion of QuartzCore in your project. You can grab the [DCRoundedSwitch](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch) controller from git hub.

Comment: useful links for custom switch http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dcroundswitch http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/simpleswitch

Comment: Yet another customizable UISwitch alternative:
https://github.com/alexnauda/ERScrollSwitch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of iOS 6, you can set

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *offImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *onImage;
```

Docs say:

> This image represents the interior contents of the switch. The image
>   you specify is composited with the switch’s rounded bezel and thumb to
>   create the final appearance.
>
> The size of this image must be less than or equal to 77 points wide
>   and 27 points tall. If you specify larger images, the edges may be
>   clipped.

Comment: Note that these properties have as of effect on iOS 7.

Answer (score 11):

I've done exactly this in iOS 6 with `onImage` and `offImage`, here are the images I used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "In iOS 7, this property has no effect." -Apple

Answer (score -26):

To change the text of an UISwitch e.g. to "Foo/Bar", do the following:

```
((UILabel *)[[[[[[_agreeAgb subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).text = @"Foo";
((UILabel *)[[[[[[_agreeAgb subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).text = @"Bar";
```

Comment: This code makes assumptions on the view hierarchy without any verifications whatsoever - don't use it! For more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806743/changing-of-uiswitch-text-in-ios-4-2

Comment: will crash in newer iOS like  4.2 and later

Comment: this is a bad answer, its best to create a custom UISwitch .. the above might not work under future versions of iOS