# How to create custom UISwitch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiswitch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing of UISwitch text in iOS 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806743/changing-of-uiswitch-text-in-ios-4-2)

Hi,
I want to change the text of UISwitch to YES/NO. Is it possible? I have seen some sample codes but nothing seems to work in IOS4.2.Could someone help please?

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question. :-)

Comment: I have already tried the same but not working..!!

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Yes ,you can change the color or text which will be like a `UISwitch` and can be implemented with the help of a customized UIView class.

**you can'nt customize UISwitch.**

Inherit UICustomSwitch from UIView.

[UICustomSwitch](http://www.catamount.com/blog/?p=1063)

Comment: I hope the control doesn't actually look like that screenshot - that's gross.

Comment: This is simply untrue. UICustomSwitch is a customised UISlider and nothing to do with UISwitch.

Comment: @maiddaparka: Correct,UISwitch has noting to do with UICustomSwitch, I edit my answer.

Comment: Cool - I've removed my downvote. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's a reimplementation of UISwitch in Sam Soffes' SSToolkit: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ssswitch

It lets you change the on/off labels, as well as using an airplane mode style switch.

Comment: Just to add mine: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2013/04/free-custom-uiswitch-flexible-colors.html which is more flexible in colors and size.