# how to change text of UISwitch for iOS SDK 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

following code was worked for me in xcode 3 but not in code 4 
should i have to change something ?

```
[switchViewSession setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f,260.0f)];
((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchViewSession subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:12.0f];
((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchViewSession subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).text = @"Pause";

((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchViewSession subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:10.0f];
((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchViewSession subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).text = @"Continue";
[switchViewSession setOn:YES];
cell.accessoryView = switchViewSession;
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Have you tried stepping through and making sure that since you are enumerating through so many subviews you are getting the object you want? As an aside, this could really do with some refactoring.

Comment: I'll add another comment, to say see [what Kevin Ballard said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806743/changing-of-uiswitch-text-in-ios-4-2/4809479#4809479) to answer a question with similar code. It seems that they've changed the internal layout between versions and your assumptions about the view hierarchy no longer hold.

Comment: @Abizern i read already but still dont know how to change text of uiswitch

Answer (score 1):

Check it out   http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ssswitch

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how it is done in the [open source replacement](https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl) and see if that helps.