# UISwitch and localization

Tags: objective-c, localization, uiswitch

i've a classic UISwitch with ON/OFF options.
Changing language on the device, i will have 1 / 0, but i want still ON/OFF, i've searched but i don't find any "fast" solution, have you any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way Apple setup the default behaviour of a UISwitch. You could subclass it to get what you want - but it may not be the quick solution you're after.

I did also find this, might be of use:

[Changing the text on a UISwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711180/changing-the-text-on-a-uiswitch)