# Set text of UISwitch in XCode

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4, uiswitch

How can I set the text of the left and right label of a UISwitch in XCode4 (iOS4) ?

Searched for a solution but need a simple direct solution in the sourcecode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711180/changing-the-text-on-a-uiswitch/3397561#3397561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customizing the switch itself is I think impossible, and if possible only using private APIs, and could cause a lot of problems depending on the firmware. An App Store safe way is using a UISlider.

Answer (score 0):

From [UISwitch Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html): `The UISwitch class is not customizable.`

Use a [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) instead with 2 segments and [segControl setMomentary:NO], then use the `- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment` method to set the title.