# how to change text of UISwitch from 0,1 to on,off

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

hi all I added the UISwitch using interface builder but the heading of UISwitch come as 0/1 I want to convert it into on/off , please help how can I do this?

Comment: can you please post your code how do you create UISwitch ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the text on a UISwitch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711180/changing-the-text-on-a-uiswitch)

Comment: http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not accept customized UISwitch.

Either you can create your own controller,similar to switch using 0.png &1.png image.