# Setting custom switch

Tags: ios, customization, uiswitch

I've found this [Former topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711180/changing-the-text-on-a-uiswitch) about how to customize a switch on iOS 6.

But I don't know how to use the answer :

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *offImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *onImage;
```

Where do I have to put these 2 lines ? In a .h file or .m file ? In the ViewController file where my switch is ?

Moreover, how can I set links between my images and these two lines (I have to call my images "offimage.png" and "onimage.png" ?)

Answer (score 1):

Under iOS 7 the On-and Off-Image are not working anymore.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

"In iOS 7, this property has no effect."

Answer (score 0):

`onImage` and `offImage` are properties of `UISwitch` - you don't add the code to your code. When you have created an instance of `UISwitch` you can then set the on and off images by setting those properties to the appropriate `UIImage` instances.

Answer (score 0):

To complete my question,
I have just to put this line in the .m file :

```
switch_name.onImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.jpg"];
```