# Customize Switch on iOS with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a need to include the functionality of the Switch object in my app. I'm writing the app in C# with Monotouch. By default, the Switch component shows either "ON" or "OFF". My question is, is there a way to change this text to be "YES" or "NO"?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but which version of iOS are you developing for?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981061/change-label-of-uiswitch

Comment: Are you going to publish the app in App Store?

Comment: Yes. I would like to publish the app in the App Store

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't customize the words in the UISwitch control even in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a UISegmentedControl to acheive this behavior.