# Changing UISwitch text to yes/no in iOS 6 Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, uiswitch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Label of UISWitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981061/change-label-of-uiswitch)

How to create uiswitch with yes/no in ios6 xcode 4.5.Tried customizing a switch but did not achieve the result.
    Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Thilo But that holds good in ios 4.2 will the same code be used in ios6 ?

Comment: @Abizern But that holds good in ios 4.2 will the same code be used in ios6 ?

Comment: @Justin Satyr  But that holds good in ios 4.2 will the same code be used in ios6 ?

Comment: @Scott Wales  But that holds good in ios 4.2 will the same code be used in ios6 ?

Comment: @BNL But that holds good in ios 4.2 will the same code be used in ios6 ?

Answer (score 1):

Make a UISwitch Control. Then add an action which listens to the ValueChanged of the control. Remember to add the UISwitch to your view at the correct placement, here i am just making 40 x 40 switch.

```
UISwitch *switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
[switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In the switchTappedMethod,  you find the state with this value:

```
-(void) switchTapped: (id) sender {
UISwitch *switchControl = (UISwitch*) sender;
BOOL value = switchControl.isOn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hakonbogen.But How do I achieve it in UISwitch?

Comment: you can use the `selectedSegmentIndex` to check if the user has selected yes or no.

Comment: @Hakonbogen Thanks again but the label still would be on/off how do I make that into yes/no ?

Comment: Here is the solution. Could you check my answer? http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/03/iphone-dev-robust-uiswitch-label-swaps/

Comment: @JasonWood I can't se a reason for it to not work. The thread that is marked duplicate has other answers as well. One of those should work :-)

Comment: @Hakonbogen  Thanks for all the help.Will check out the code.